# Какая нужна библиотека?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, com, office, ms-word

1.Поставил Visual studio 2012 на другой комп:
2.Работаю на C# с COM-объектами MS office Word.
3.На другом компе работает всё ок. На этом же я доставлял PIA для офиса. И вот ещё вылетает вот такая ошибочка:
"Невозможно привести COM-объект типа \"Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass\" к интерфейсному типу \"Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application\". Операция завершилась со сбоем, поскольку вызов QueryInterface COM-компонента для интерфейса с IID \"{00020970-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\" возвратил следующую ошибку:Библиотека не зарегистрирована. (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY))."}

4.Не могу понять какую библиотеку он хочет.

Comment: Может, у вас не поставлен Office на другой машине?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже что версии не совпадают.

Попробуйте зайти в реестр "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/TypeLib/{00020905-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"
должно быть 2 папки с названиями 8.х... Одна содержит ключи вторая пустая (с одним ключём "Default"). Пустую нужно удалить .

Comment: Вы точно уверены, что ручное удаление параметров из реестра — хорошая идея, и не приведёт чужую систему в нерабочее состояние?

Comment: Зделайте backup ветки, тем более нужно удалить одну лишь папку с пустым ключём. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42936222/error-printing-when-using-microssoft-office-interop здесь помоему описывается аналогичная проблема

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!! использовал  вот этот вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42936222/error-printing-when-using-microssoft-office-interop. но теперь мне интересно, как они это узнали, что дело именно в реестре??